# SpringBoot Application not release connections on tests

Tags: spring-boot

There are several `@JDBCTest`, `@SpringBootTest` in my tests.

I got `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already` Error when I run `gradle test`.

While test is running, DB connections are not released after each test is finished.

Why my application not releases DB connections or not ends itself?

Comment: How do you connect to the database?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I'm using Exposed. So, run `Database.connect(dataSource)` at starting of the application.